# Simplify Expressions used to define Region

Tags: simplifying-expressions, regions

For example,

```
RegionPlot[{x + y > 1, x - y > 1, y - x > 1, -x - y > 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

can be somehow written as:

```
RegionPlot[{Abs[x] + Abs[y] > 1}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

My question is whether Mathematica can simplified the first group of expressions to the second one?

### Updates

I think I do not make the question clear. I think conditions in

`{x + y > 1, x - y > 1, y - x > 1, -x - y > 1}`

describing the same region as

`{Abs[x] + Abs[y] > 1}`

Therefore, the question is whether `{x + y > 1, x - y > 1, y - x > 1, -x - y > 1}`
can be reduce to `{Abs[x] + Abs[y] > 1}`. or, generally, is there any method can simplify the expressions used to describe a region?

Answer (score 2):

```
RegionPlot[
 Or @@ {x + y > 1, x - y > 1, y - x > 1, -x - y > 1}, {x, -2, 
  2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

suffices
[image]

Comment: Sorry, I think I do not ask a clear question. If you have time, please check the updated question. Thanks!

Comment: @Kattern I apologize for delay. Timezone differences...I hope your aim has been achieved:)

Comment: No, maybe it is not a good idea to try to simplify those expressions.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't been able to turn one into the other, but they can both be reduced to the most basic form, which is the same:

```
exp1 = 
 Reduce[x + y > 1 || x - y > 1 || y - x > 1 || -x - y > 1, {x, y}, 
  Reals]
exp2 = Reduce[Abs[x] + Abs[y] > 1, {x, y}, Reals]
exp1 == exp2
(* x < -1 || (-1 <= x <= 0 && (y < -1 - x || y > 1 + x)) || (0 < 
    x <= 1 && (y < -1 + x || y > 1 - x)) || x > 1 *)
(* x < -1 || (-1 <= x <= 0 && (y < -1 - x || y > 1 + x)) || (0 <
     x <= 1 && (y < -1 + x || y > 1 - x)) || x > 1 *)
(* True *)
```

and it can be plotted the same,

```
RegionPlot[exp1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

giving the same output as in ubpdqn's answer